# Determining truth of one event given another problem

Tags: logic

[image]

---For question iii---

If you assume Alice is telling the truth then Bob must also be. This means Carol is lying which means David is telling the truth. But if David is telling the truth then Bob must be lying which is a contradiction (we said Bob is telling the truth earlier).

How would I ago about answering the question? Am I meant to only consider statements a1 and a4 (meaning David is lying) or do I mention that the assumption leads to a contradiction?

If, for argument's sake, you assume that Alice is lying then it still leads to a contradiction, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with you:  Alice is a liar.

Notation:  We'll just first letters for our suspects.  Also we'll see , e.g., A is T to mean that Alice is telling the truth, similarly "B is L" means Bob is a liar.

From (3);  either C or D is T (possibly both)

Case I:  C is T.

Then B is L, from (2). 
Then A is L, from (1).

Case II. D is T.

Then B is L from (4)
Whence A is L from (1)

No use trusting Alice, I fear.

Comment: Right, but what is to be said about David then? Simply, we don't know?

Comment: Well, one can prove (or disprove) any statement from a false premise.  Hence, yes.. I'd say that nothing can meaningfully be deduced about David. But I suspect that there was an error in the way the problem was posed.  I doubt it was meant to come to this sort of argument.

Comment: Agreed, sadly there aren't any solutions provided :/